# CLI PHP configuration

Tags: php5

I'm getting a Deprecated warning despite the following setting in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

I don't see a CLI specific php.ini, Do I need to create create one?  Where else would this setting be coming from?

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which distribution?

/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini - try /etc/php5/cli/php.ini if it's present or try from shell #php -i | grep php.ini and edit this file.

Answer (score 0):

Check [PHP's documentation about the configuration files](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php).

In Gentoo Linux, the configuration for CLI PHP is under `/etc/php/cli-php5`.

Comment: I've looked closer, on Ubuntu-server (I should've specified) `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`